# Unable to display the content loaded from MemoryStream in a particular paragraph in Gembox.Document

Tags: c#, memorystream, gembox-document

I have a document that is made up of different paragraphs

```
<p> paragraph 1<p/>
<p> paragraph 2<p/>
<p> paragraph 3 content is from an uploaded pdf document <p/>
<p> paragraph 4<p/>
<p> paragraph 5<p/>
```

Content of paragraph 3 is from a previously uploaded pdf document loaded as a MemoryStream.

How do I ensure that the content of paragraph 3 is placed between paragraphs 2 and 4?

currently, I am able to load it before paragraph 1 or after paragraph 5, using

```
var document = new DocumentModel();
 //
 // other paragraphs and sections
 //
        
var financialAnalysisDocument = DocumentModel.Load(data.FinancialAnalysisDocumentStream, loanOption);

document.Content.End.InsertRange(financialAnalysisDocument.Content;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
document.Sections[0].Blocks[1].Content.End.InsertRange(financialAnalysisDocument.Content);
```

However, because the `financialAnalysisDocument.Content` is a `ContentRange` of the whole `DocumentModel`, this will result in inserting `Section` elements between "paragraph 2" and "paragraph 4".

I'm not sure if that is what you want, so perhaps this would be a better fit for your needs:

```cs
document.Sections[0].Blocks[1].Content.End.InsertRange(
    financialAnalysisDocument.Sections[0].Blocks.Content);
```